# Robust time zone conversion in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 library that is shared by both an ASP.NET Core API app targeting .NET 6 and a .NET MAUI app which is also a .NET 6 based app.

The problem I'm running into is that the following works on the ASP.NET Core app which runs on Azure App service but fails on .NET MAUI.

```
var mtnStdTimeValue = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(myUtcDateTimeValue, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Mountain Standard Time"));
```

If I change `Mountain Standard Time` to `America/Denver`, the above code works fine on .NET MAUI but fails on ASP.NET Core if I run it on Azure App Service, though it works fine if I run it on my laptop.

I read this article and my impression was that the `TimeZoneInfo` had been improved to handle both Windows based IDs as well as IANA IDs.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/

What do I need to use here if I want this code to run without any issues on both apps?

Comment: You can use my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library. In terms of ASP.NET Core though, I'd expect it to be fine on .NET 6 - what version of .NET is Azure App Service using?

Comment: Thanks but I’d rather handle this with what’s already in the box.

Comment: Well if the two environments you're using simply don't have a time zone database in common, then "what's already in the box" is insufficient. (I'd expect MAUI to be okay with the Windows time zone IDs too, mind you - again, assuming it really is using .NET 6.)

Comment: You're right but I'm changing my approach so that I don't use time zones and use UTC offset instead. Of course, there are situations when this is not feasible but in my case, it is. As per your comment about .NET MAUI, clearly it is using .NET 6 because it wants me to use `America/Denver` which is meaningless to .NET 2.0 Standard. I think ultimately, I'll have to switch to .NET 6 for my shared class libraries because in the article, they talk about new methods .NET team has introduced that will try to convert Windows ID's to IANA IDs. Both my API and MAUI apps would be happy with .NET 6 libs.

Comment: "because it wants me to use America/Denver which is meaningless to .NET 2.0 Standard" - no, that depends on the environment in which the actual code is running. Targeting .NET Standard 2.0 shouldn't make any difference to that. (I'd be surprised if changing your library targeting made any difference.) When running in Linux for example, .NET Core has *always* used the IANA IDs. But in .NET 6, I'd expect both Windows and IANA IDs to be usable everywhere.

Comment: I see. I didn't know that. I appreciate your telling me that. Again, ultimately, switching to .NET 6 for my class libraries would be beneficial.